# SSH over serial on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, forwarding, serial

I need to establish SSH connection over serial between Windows and Linux machine. I used socat on Linux side to do forwarding from uart to SSH server at localhost and it works fine.

Goal:
SSH client - Windows(UART) ------------ Linux (UART) - SSH server at localhost

To test the Linux side, I used Putty on Windows side to open COM port connection to SSH server on Linux, and it works.

Now the problem is, I need to use SSH client on Windows side.
I tried HW VSP3 (from [HW_Group](https://www.hw-group.com)) to act as TCP Server and map it to my COM port. I tested it locally by opening the COM port using Putty, and telnet to the local TCP server. I expected to see what I type on telnet terminal to appear on the Putty, and vice versa. I didn't see anything.

Probably because it's not the intended usage of HW VSP3. I also tried TCPCOM32 to no avail.
I explored Putty port forwarding, I didn't see a way to forward the packet to the serial port.

My question is, what can I do on Windows side to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to setup a PPP server on the Linux side on the serial port, and then configure Windows as a PPP client over the serial link.

That way you will get standard IP networking between the two machines.

Comment: Thanks Tero. I will give it a shot. So, it seems that it's not feasible to run SSH over serial.

Comment: The general idea in IP is that one implements IP on top of different layer 2 technologies like serial, ethernet, Wi-Fi etc. and then applications run on top of IP. That way applications only need to support IP.

Comment: Ah, got it. Serial is the physical layer, PPP is the data link layer, and IP is the network layer. I thought I would be able to do like "socat" on Windows' side - as socat is much simpler on Linux's side. I am curious how the use of socat seems to "bypass" several OSI layers.